# How to move a boolean value from one array to another in python

Tags: python, arrays, boolean

I am recently solving a coding problem. It ask me to move all 0s in one array to the end of the array. Like [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]->[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0].

The reality is there could be any type of data in the original array, for example, 
[0, "A", 1 , None, False, True, 0, 0, 20, 1, 0.0]

what I am doing is looping the array, compare if it is 0, if it is, put it into another array. If it is not, increase the counter, at the end put the same amount of 0s as the counter.  However, it treats the Boolean Value False as 0, so I can't do this, I am just curious if there is a way that can separate False from 0, and put into another array as False in Python.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this an assignment where it's asking for algorithm design or can you just use sorted in rev order?

Comment: `False` is implemented as `0` but has an other type. So, check value and type!

Comment: @KlausD. Try this: `isinstance(True, int)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That's because `isinstance()` check for supertypes as well. Use `type(False) == int` instead.

Comment: @KlausD. I concur, what I meant to say was that simply checking type isn't enough...

Answer (score 1):

Use the test in your algorithm, to check if the value is the integer 0 and not the bool.

```
test = lambda x: True if x is 0 else False

list_ = [0, "A", 1 , None, False, True, 0, 0, 20, 1, 0.0]

print(sorted(list_, key=test)) #['A', 1, None, False, True, 20, 1, 0.0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: In the problem, 0.0 is treat as 0, if it is detected, it will be put to the end of the array with a 0, not 0.0.

Comment: 0.0 is 0      >>>False

Comment: I tried your way, 0.0 is put back as 0.0, in the problem if a 0.0 need to be 0 and put back. For example, [1, 0, 0, 2, 0.0, 1] should be [1,2,1,0,0,0]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of *is* which does an identity comparison. Observe the following example:

```
>>> n = 0
>>> n is 0
True
>>> n is False
False
>>> False is n
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into some issues with `0.0` so, i made some changes

```
array = [0, "A", 1 , None, False, True, 0, 0, 20, 1, 0.0]
filt = lambda x: True if x==0 and type(x) is not bool else False
print(sorted(array,key=filt))
```

The `x==0` will allow you to filter the float, and `type(x) in not bool` will help you with the boolean `False`